# How do i fix "Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin" error in Javascript (jquery) with webworks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, blackberry-webworks

I am trying to create a webworks app and trying to use jquery to post to a REST api -

I get the following error

"Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin"

The javascript tries to post to a rest api using jquery

I am getting the error when running it on chrome or firefox. Some of the solutions I see on stackoverflow says that I need to run it on a webserver, but I would like to run it as a webworks app and therefore need to have it stand alone. Also, if I run this as hta (html application) it runs fine.

Comment: Have a look at:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595515/xmlhttprequest-error-origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin

Comment: I thought only JSONP allowed cross site AJAX requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) is in play here. If you can alter the api you are calling, you could use [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control) on the newer browsers. Or make the api support JSONP. If you cannot change the service you are calling, you are sort of out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

For allowing BlackBerry 10 to call an URL from an WebWorks app you need to add this line inside your config.xml : `<access uri="*" subdomains="true" />`

Hope this will solve your issue